# split a string in each line in a file and print the fields

Tags: arrays, perl, split

I have the following details in 'input.txt' file.

```
 /u02/users/student1/marks score: 97 subject: sub1 status: passed
 /u02/users/student2/marks score: 20 subject: sub1 status: failed
 /u02/users/student3/marks score: 80 subject: sub1 status: passed
 /u02/users/student4/marks score: 60 subject: sub1 status: passed
 /u02/users/student5/marks score: 50 subject: sub1 status: passed
 /u02/users/student6/marks score: 45 subject: sub1 status: failed
 /u02/users/student7/marks score: 99 subject: sub1 status: passed
```

I'm trying to split the strings and print specific fields.
The output i'm looking for:
    student1 marks score: 97
    student2 marks score: 20
    student3 marks score: 80
    student4 marks score: 60 
    student5 marks score: 50 
    student6 marks score: 45 
    student7 marks score: 99

Here is the code i wrote. but looks to be having some problem and getting below error. please correct me.

syntax error at script.pl line 6, near ")
print"
Execution of script.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
while (defined (my $line = <>)) {
my @lines = split(/\//, $line)
print "$lines[3] $lines[4] $lines[5] $lines[6]\n";
}
```

Comment: i parsed the input file perl script.pl input.txt

Comment: Simply, Use missed the semicolon end of the split statement `my @lines = split(/\//, $line);`

Comment: apart from rhe regex, this isn't really possible simply printing the values based on the delimiters ?

Comment: I'm considering the delimiter as '/'

Answer (score 1):

Your split command is splitting on `/`, which produces 5 fields with the first one always empty. The fields you want are 3 and 4. To get the output you want, you need to remove the subject after the score, for which you could use the `s//` operator:

```
my $student = $lines[3];
my $score = $lines[4];
$score =~ s/ subject:.*$//;
print "$student $score\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

In such cases i'm using regex built from the source.

You have the line:

```
/u02/users/student1/marks score: 97 subject: sub1 status: passed
```

From this line you really need student and it's score, so you are building regex like:

```
/u02/users/(.+?)/(marks score: \d+) subject:
```

And the code will be:

```
use v5.10;

while (my $line = <>) {
    if( $line =~ m{/u02/users/(.+?)/(marks score: \d+) subject} ){
        say "$1 $2";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the semicolon and the end of the splitting. That is the reason of the syntax error

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
while (defined (my $line = <>)) {
    my @lines = split(/\//, $line);
    my ($scr) = $lines[4] =~m/(.+?)subject/;
    print " $lines[3] $scr \n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very unclear what you want to achieve, but the syntax error is because you have a missing semicolon after `my @lines = split(/\//, $line)`

You will also find that your `split` doesn't divide each line as you expect. For instance, the first line of input produces this

```
@lines = (
  "    ",
  "u02",
  "users",
  "student1",
  "marks score: 97 subject: sub1 status: passed\n",
)
```

You don't say what result you're hoping for, but at a guess you want just the varying information: the student, score, subject and status

You could write it this way, splitting the data on *either* slashes or whitespace

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

while ( <DATA> ) {
    my @lines = split qr{/|\s};
    shift @lines until $lines[0] =~ /\S/;
    print "$lines[2] $lines[5] $lines[7] $lines[9]\n";
}

__DATA__
/u02/users/student1/marks score: 97 subject: sub1 status: passed
/u02/users/student2/marks score: 20 subject: sub1 status: failed
/u02/users/student3/marks score: 80 subject: sub1 status: passed
/u02/users/student4/marks score: 60 subject: sub1 status: passed
/u02/users/student5/marks score: 50 subject: sub1 status: passed
/u02/users/student6/marks score: 45 subject: sub1 status: failed
/u02/users/student7/marks score: 99 subject: sub1 status: passed
```

#### output

```
student1 97 sub1 passed
student2 20 sub1 failed
student3 80 sub1 passed
student4 60 sub1 passed
student5 50 sub1 passed
student6 45 sub1 failed
student7 99 sub1 passed
```